# Trying to host my shiny app for everyone to see with shiny-server

Tags: shiny, ubuntu-16.04, web-hosting, shiny-server

### EDIT

Since no one answered I guess I may not be stating my problem the right way, so I decided to give it a go and add [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/_eIwgntFPOM) as part of the question. Hope it clarifies my question.

Hello Everyone:

I am a longtime R and shiny user, but a first time shiny-server user with little experience. I am trying to  host a shiny app, and I was trying to follow the discussion in this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/cBrh2abDvAs) but still haven’t been able to figure it out, so far I changed the listening port from 3838 to 80 as recommended in the thread and also tried to access the "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf" folder as shown in the thread, but it does not exist in my ubuntu.

My app runs fine locally and I can see it by typing http://146.155.169.145/Example/ in my browser, but  when I try to access it from other computers I can’t, it says connection timed out as shown bellow. As stated above, I have a lot of experience in R and  Shiny, but I do not know much about hosting.

[image]

My shiny-server.conf is the following:

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
  listen 80;

  # Define a location at the base URL
  location / {

    # Host the directory of Shiny Apps stored in this directory
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Log all Shiny output to files in this directory
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # When a user visits the base URL rather than a particular application,
    # an index of the applications available in this directory will be shown.
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

and I am using ubuntu 16.04

Let me know if I can give you more information

Thanks

Comment: Check if your server's firewall is blocking your specified port. Last time I did a `shiny-server` setup, that was the only issue I ran into.

Comment: Tnaks @GregordeCilia Would I have to ask someone in my institution, or is there any way I can check from the terminal if there are any firewalls preventing it?

Comment: TBH, I am really not a linux pro and quite some time passed since I did this setup. Maybe look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/309052/check-if-port-is-open-or-closed-on-a-linux-server/309062) to check which ports are blocked. Opening ports on the firewall definitely requires root priviliges though.

Comment: Hi, what error you see exactly when you try to run your app on another computer? Is it grayed out?

Comment: Sorry for the delay @Bogaso I added it in the question now, it says connection timed out, I have tried it from different computers

Comment: When I had a similar problem with my AWS as well as with Digitalocean hosts, I increased RAM from 4 GB to 8GB in Digitalocean. You can have a try with that approach. Also, you can add below 2 lines at the end of Config file : app_init_timeout 20000;
    app_idle_timeout 10000;

Comment: Thank you @Bogaso, I don't thing that is the problem, I am running it at a local computer with 16GB of RAM, and it is only running that app, I think it is a lot more basic than that, I believe I don really know how to make my IP available to everyone. If what I did what I wanted to do you should be able to type in your browser http://146.155.169.145/Example/  and see my app, am I asking the wrong question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the problem is the memory or your computer, for me is like you are protected by a router or firewall. If you have a router, you need to set up a demilitarized zone or similar approach and permit incoming connections (if your computer is at your house is more straightforward, because at the university have proxy and firewall). Are you tried something like what Dean Attali proposes on his webpage? https://deanattali.com/2015/05/09/setup-rstudio-shiny-server-digital-ocean/

Maybe you can try something like that, but if you want to rent a virtual server (VPS) need to know if this server can run R, some VPSs are only for webpage server.